# How to clear LastActivityViewer by removing registry keys? Which keys would I remove?

Tags: java, registry

So I'm using the WinRegistry class, found in an answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) page.

I need to stop my JAR file showing up in LastActivityViewer - which apparently uses Registry Keys to obtain it's information. Now on [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_activity_view.html) site, it explains which registry keys to delete.

I specifically need to clear; Windows Prefetch Folder, Open/Save MRU list in the registry and the Windows Shell Bag Registry (you will understand if you look at the site I linked).

So this much I've figured out, but basically, the WinRegistry class has a deleteKey and deleteValue method which I can use - but how do I know the parameters that I should enter / which method to use?

Please help me on this; I've been looking everywhere and cannot seem to find an answer.

Proof of research:
[Finding a specific registry key using java in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227261/finding-a-specific-registry-key-using-java-in-windows)
https://coderanch.com/t/517229/java/Editing-reading-windows-registry-java

Disclaimer: I've tried to word this question as understandable as possible. If it isn't clear then please leave a comment about what is unclear.

```
 try {
        //ls = WinRegistry.readStringSubKeys(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        //        "Software\\Classes\\Local Settings\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\");
        WinRegistry.deleteKey(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\ComDlg32\\OpenSavePidlMRU\\jar");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is returning a NPE -> will try to fix, but in the meanwhile any help appreciated.

EDIT: I've been looking through regedit and I found this; OpenSavePidlMRU folder which contains "exe, jar, jpg, png" etc inside.  I used the RegistryWin.deleteKey method and the jar file disappeared from the registry - this is a good thing but is it dangerous?